# Is it possible to use PK as FK when creating a related object NOT asking DB?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to use this code for creating a new M2M object

```
course_id = int(request.POST['course'])
    if not Status.objects.get(course=course_id, user=request.user.profile, role="student"):
        rel = Status(course=course_id, user=request.user.profile,
                     role="student")
        rel.save()
```

And result is

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "Status.course" must be a "Course" instance.
```

I know that is possible to use if I do stuff like this:

```
course = Course.objects.get(pk=request.POST['course'])
rel = Status(course=course, user=request.user.profile,
                 role="student")
```

but in this way I ask the Course object from DB (after assign I don't need this). This is overhead as I think.

It is possible to assign a related object with having only PK, NOT asking this object from DB?

Comment: Why don't you simply use the models.ManyToManyField?  docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: I need to use additional fields in this "auxillary" table, so it seems to me there are no ways to make this in other way

Answer (score 0):

You have the problem here :

```
if not Status.objects.get(**course=course_id**, user=request.user.profile, role="student"):
```

Status is expecting a couse instance and you are passing an id. Intead what you have do:

```
course_id = int(request.POST['course'])
if not Status.objects.get(course__pk=course_instance, user=request.user.profile, role="student"):
            rel = Status(course=course_id, user=request.user.profile,
                         role="student")
            rel.save()
```

Comment: I already know this (in 2nd part of the question I meant it). I asked, IS there a way not to ask object from DB? I don't need the actual Course object so asking this object from DB is overhead

Comment: Yes but if you need to check for this course the Status you need as is required by models. Another thing what you can do instead is to check the pk of the course as is edited